# Lexicographical sorting

Tags: algorithm, lexicographic

I'm doing a problem that says "concatenate the words to generate the lexicographically lowest possible string." from a competition.

Take for example this string: `jibw ji jp bw jibw`

The actual output turns out to be: `bw jibw jibw ji jp`

When I do sorting on this, I get: `bw ji jibw jibw jp`.

Does this mean that this is not sorting? If it is sorting, does "lexicographic" sorting take into consideration pushing the shorter strings to the back or something?

I've been doing some reading on [lexigographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) and I don't see any point or scenarios on which this is used, do you have any?

Comment: You're looking for a point in a **competitioun question**?!

Comment: I already lost that point because a friend pointed out this problem in my algorithm. So I'm here to find out whats the point of lexicographic and why was I wrong.

Comment: @Nabb, yep, just heard of it and thought I'd try it.

Comment: Since the number of words per test case is <= 9, you can actually just iterate over all possible permutations. No cleverness needed for this question.

Comment: @Shawn Please delete this question until the contest is over. Although you lost the point, it's still enabling others to cheat which could get you and them [disqualified](http://www.facebook.com/hackercup/terms.php).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems that what you're looking for is a better understanding of the question, so let me just make it clear. The usual sorting on strings *is* lexicographic sorting. If you sort the strings [jibw, ji, jp, bw, jibw] into lexicographic order, the sorted sequence *is* [bw, ji, jibw, jibw, jp], which is what you got. So your problem is not with understanding the word "lexicographic"; you already understand it correctly.

Your problem is that you're misreading the question. The question doesn't ask you to *sort* the strings in lexicographic order. (If it did, the answer you got by sorting would be correct.) Instead, it asks you to produce *one* string, got by *concatenating* the input strings in some order (i.e., making one string without spaces), so that the resulting single string is lexicographically minimal.

To illustrate the difference, consider the string you get by concatenating the sorted sequence, and the answer string:

```
bwjijibwjibwjp //Your answer
bwjibwjibwjijp //The correct answer
```

Now when you compare these two strings — note that you're just comparing two 14-character strings, not two sequences of strings — you can see that the correct answer is indeed lexicographically smaller than your answer: your answer starts with "bwjij", while the correct answer starts with "bwjib", and "bwjib" comes before "bwjij" in lexicographic order.

Hope you understand the question now. It is not a sorting question at all. (That is, it is not a problem of sorting the input strings. You *could* do sorting on all possible strings got by permuting and concatenating the input strings; this is one way of solving the problem if the number of input strings is small.)

Comment: Not a sorting question at all? If all the words are the same length, it is COMPLETELY a sorting question.

Comment: @Nabb: Yes, in various special cases this problem can be solved by sorting — and even in the general case, it can be solved, not necessarily efficiently, by sorting a special set of strings. But in general, as stated, it is not the same problem as sorting the set of strings given as input. I already said this in the last paragraph. :-)

Comment: Maybe you haven't noticed this, but there is a trivial reduction to sorting (as well as simple algorithms to output the strings after sorting lexicographically) -- which I'm not going to post yet for obvious reasons. If you're going to suggest that sorting isn't the way to go, then by all means provide more details, although the complexity of sorting is trivially a lower bound though.

Comment: @Nabb: I'm not saying that the problem cannot be solved by sorting, only that the problem is not identical to sorting the input strings, as the OP seemed to be misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this into a trivial sorting problem by comparing word1 + word2 against word2 + word1. In Python:

```
def cmp_concetanate(word1, word2):
    c1 = word1 + word2
    c2 = word2 + word1
    if c1 < c2:
        return -1
    elif c1 > c2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Using this comparison function with the standard sort solves the problem.

Comment: You could use python's cmp() funtion to get a simplier code: words.sort(cmp=lambda a, b: cmp(a+b, b+a))

Answer (score 1):

I've been using F# in this Facebook hacker cup. Learned quite a bit in this competition. Since the documentation on F# on the web is still rare, I think I might as well share a bit here.

This problem requests you to sort a list of strings based on a customized comparison method. Here is my code snippet in F#.

```
    let comparer (string1:string) (string2:string) =
         String.Compare(string1 + string2, string2 + string1)

    // Assume words is an array of strings that you read from the input
    // Do inplace sorting there
    Array.sortInPlaceWith comparer words
    // result contains the string for output
    let result = Array.fold (+) "" words
```

Answer (score 1):

//Use this block of code to print lexicographically sorted characters of an array or it can be used in many ways.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<conio.h>

  void combo(int,int,char[],char[],int*,int*,int*);

  void main()
  {
      char a[4]={'a','b','c'};
      char a1[10];
      int i=0,no=0;
      int l=0,j=0;
      combo(0,3,a,a1,&j,&l,&no);
      printf("%d",no);
      getch();
  }
  void combo(int ctr,int n,char a[],char a1[],int*j,int*l,int*no)
  {
      int i=0;
      if(ctr==n)
      {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            printf("%c",a1[i]);
        printf("\n");
        (*no)++;
        (*j)++;
        if((*j)==n)
        { 
            *l=0;
             *j=0;
        }
        else
        *l=1;       
        getch();
      }
      else
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        if(*l!=1)
            *j=i;
        a1[ctr]=a[*j];
        combo(ctr+1,n,a,a1,j,l,no);
        }
    }
```

Comment: the array needs to be sorted before passing it to the combo function

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted shows that mere sorting would not generate the lexicographically lowest string.
For the given problem, you would need to apply some additional trick to determine which string should come before which(as of now, I can't think of the exact method)

The actual output does not violate the condition for lexicographically lowest word.

Answer (score 0):

The sort command on linux also does Lexicographic sorting and generates the output in the order bw ji jibw jibw jp

Answer (score 0):

Check what happened here:

If you just apply a lexicographic sort you'll get bw ji jibw jibw jp
but if you analyze token by token you'll find that "bwjibw" (bw, jibw) is lexicographicaly lower than "bwjijibw" (bw, ji, jibw) that's why the answer is bw jibw jibw ji jp because first you should append bwjibwjibw and after that you could concatenate ji and jp to get the lowest string.

Comment: This means the algorithm will have to contain some sort of a permutation? Is there any link to articles you have on lexicographic analysis?

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick involving only sorting, which would work for this problem as the max string length is specified, would be to pad all strings up to max length with the first letter in the string. Then you sort the padded strings, but output the original unpadded ones. For ex. for string length 2 and inputs  b and ba you would sort bb and ba which would give you ba and bb, and hence you should output bab.

Comment: where you'd break ties in padded strings using the original strings

Answer (score 0):

Prasun's trick works if you instead pad with a special "placeholder" character that could be weighted to be greater than "z" in a string sort function. The result would give you the order of lowest lexicographic combination.

Answer (score 0):

The contest is over so I am posting a possible solution, not the most efficient but one way of doing it

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;
   int main()
  {
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("output.txt");
int numTestCases;
int numStrings;
string* ptr=NULL;
char*ptr2=NULL;
string tosort;
scanf("%d",&numTestCases);
for(int i=0;i<numTestCases;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&numStrings);
    ptr=new string[numStrings];
    for(int i=0;i<numStrings;i++)
    {
        cin>>ptr[i];
    }
    sort(ptr,ptr+numStrings);
    for(int i=0;i<numStrings;i++)
    {
        next_permutation(ptr,ptr+numStrings);
    }
    tosort.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<numStrings;i++)
    {
        tosort.append(ptr[i]);
    }
    ptr2=&tosort[i];

    cout<<tosort<<endl;
    myfile<<tosort<<endl;   
    delete[]ptr;
}
return 0;
  }
```

I am using algorithms from the STL library in c++, the prev_permutation function simply generates a permutation sorted lexicographically